For two linear codes $C$ and $D$, why is $D^\perp \subset C$ equivalent to $H_C\times H_D^T=0$?
I have been reading this paper about Quantum QC-LDPC codes which are a subset of CSS codes, and it says that "For the linear codes $C$ and $D$, it is said that $C$ and $D$ satisfy the twisted condition if $D^\perp \subset C$ or equivalently $C^\perp \subset D$. It is easy to verify that this condition is equivalent to $H_C\times H_D^T=0$ where $H_C$ and $H_D$ are parity-check matrices of $C$ and $D$ respectively". How can I prove that
$D^\perp \subset C \Leftrightarrow C^\perp \subset D \Leftrightarrow H_C\times H_D^T=0$? I tried using the definition of dual code, generator and parity check matrices, but I couldn't easily verify this proposition.

Hint:
The rows of $H_D$ are codewords of $D^\perp$; in fact, $H_D$ is a generator matrix for $D^\perp$. Hence, the columns of $H_D^T$ are codewords of $D^\perp$ and so the statement that $H_c\times H_D^T = 0$ is telling you that every codeword $x \in D^\perp$ satisfies $H_C x^T = 0$. What, if anything, does this tell you about the codewords of $D^\perp$ and the relationship of $D^\perp$ and $C$?
